# Android SDK WifiManager methods won't work?

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

For some reasons, this ain't working:

```
    wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    if(wifi.isWifiEnabled())
    {
        tvStatus.setText("You WiFi is enabled");
    }
    else
    {
        tvStatus.setText("You WiFi is disabled");
    }
```

Why aint this working, am i missing something?
And it compiles and everything but when i want to run it on my phone it gives me a force quit error

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine the Java stack trace associated with your "force quit error".

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the right permissions for using WiFi declared in your Manifest.
I think you will be needing [`ACCESS_WIFI_STATE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_WIFI_STATE) at a mininum, or if you wish to enable WiFi too, then [`CHANGE_WIFI_STATE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CHANGE_WIFI_STATE) will come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

```
ConnectivityManager conMgr;
NetworkInfo netInfo;
WifiManager wifiMgr;

conMgr=(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(context.WIFI_Service);
netInfo=conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if(!(netInfo==null))
{
if(WifiMgr.isWifiEnabled())
{
//wifi  enabled
}
else
{
//wifi disabled i.e not available
}
}
```